# What is a good, hi-tech textbook on complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I am looking for an introductory textbook for Complex Analysis that is **hi-tech**.

All the books I have looked at suffer from the same problem; they're only assuming that the reader is familiar with is basic real analysis, and thus, are by design, low-tech.

I'm looking for a textbook that:

- Doesn't shy away from treating the Riemann sphere as a manifold, and
  clearly distinguishes it from $\mathbb{C}$, so it's easy to keep
  track of where my functions live.
- Gives the statement of Cauchy's theorem in a modern, algebraic topological language of (co)homology
- Actually compares the theorems, where applicable, to the $2$-dimensional real case with more than passing remarks
- Doesn't give whacky definitions of topological properties (eg. simple connectedness)

This isn't a complete list, but this should give you a good idea about what I mean by hi-tech.

Additional extras:

- Has a sane statement of Liouville's theorem. Why say that "bounded entire functions are constant" when you could be saying "the image of a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is dense or a single point"?
- Covers basic multivariable complex analysis
- Treats the logarithm, etc. as functions from a Riemann surface, rather than the clumsy "multifunction" treatment
- Treats power series formally and then passes to convergent ones

I basically want someone like John M. Lee to write a complex analysis book. (His book on Smooth Manifolds is about as good as textbooks get, in my opinion.)

The closest I have found was Cartan's text, but I'm hoping that someone on this site might know something even better.

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure "hi-tech" is the word you are looking for. More like "advanced."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, well, it depends on what you mean by advanced. I don't want the theorems to be (much) more advanced than the ones you can find in say Ahlfors. But I do want the presentation to be advanced, yes.

Comment: Advanced in a completely different direction is the treatment of single-variable complex analysis in Hormander's SCV book, where it's all done in about ten pages, developing the theory using measure theory.

Comment: "Has a sane statement of Liouville's theorem." You're being silly here. The proof of your claim follows from the classical statement of Liouville, and since Liouville stated in such a way, and it is this variant one uses mostly, it is useless to go against historical inertia and tradition.

Comment: @key: I'm not sure whether the book "Complex Analysis in One Variable" by R. Narsasimhan & Y. Nievergelt will fall into your $"{\bf hi}$-${\bf tech}"$ book list or not, but you can take a look at it. http://books.google.co.in/books?id=tnlIbsRlg1MC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=complex+analysis+raghavan+narasimhan&source=bl&ots=bGHJhBJjll&sig=pcGzNxMaSmgLX4jrdTU7JpvYRDs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bHl2VJLBApOXuAST34KIDA&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=complex%20analysis%20raghavan%20narasimhan&f=false

Comment: I would echo Narasimhan. Also, look at Forster's Riemann Surfaces book, along with Hörmander's SCV (which covers one variable in 20 pages or so, but then uses serious graduate real analysis).

Comment: If you speak spanish, my Complex Analysis Professor has some pretty good notes.

Comment: @hjhjhj57, I don't but I could try. Please share

Comment: It's still a draft with minor typos and it's analysis oriented rather than geometric, but I hope it helps: http://www.ackermath.info/teaching/unam-curso-2015-1/analisis_complejo.pdf

Comment: @hjhjhj57, in what way are these notes hi-tech? (other than being in a language I don't speak)

They don't seem to meet *any* of the criteria I list above

Comment: hehe, sorry about that. Hadn't read the whole post. Even though, it covers 5 or 6 /8 of you points.

Comment: Another book you can try is Hörmander's. Comments from [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/mill_courses/math503a/instruct.html): "Although almost 30 years old, the first chapter of this book is a startling view of one variable complex analysis by one of the originators of modern partial differential equations. Its view of the subject changed everything! The first chapter gives an approach quite distinct from the traditional 1890's style.", and, of Bernstein & Gay's book: "...this ... book is devoted to carrying out the novel approach sketched in the first chapter of Hörmander's book".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berenstein/Gay: Complex variables. Imo it satisfies the first four points. Concerning a sane statement of Liouville's theorem: the usual statement is the sane one; if you don't understand this, think harder about it. It also does not treat complex analysis in several variables, for this you should take a look at Hörmander; I am also not sure as far as power series are concerned; knowledge of formal power series is quite "low tech" (as you would put it), and so including it would be odd.

[I would describe Lee's smooth manifold as rather "low tech", in particular his rather unsophisticated treatment of $\otimes$ and algebra in general (the same is true for most algebraic topology textbooks apart from perhaps Spanier), and of de Rham cohomology. In any case it does a good job as far as geometry is concerned, and this is what it is about. In the same way you can't expect a textbook on analysis to give the most elegant/sophisticated treatment of algebra related topics, but as you are looking for something like Lee, I guess you are not looking for something that has Bourbaki level.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Berenstein/Gay looks very nice! A few points: formal power series are definitely a layer of abstraction over convergent power series. I only added it to the list, because I enjoyed Cartan's treatment of them. I'm unfortunately not familiar with the works of Bourbaki, but in any case, if you have other good books in mind, please share.

Comment: @krey certainly they are more abstract, but elementary in the same sense as the intermediate value theorem is, so they are not something sophisticated or anything.